# Entity Navigation Property IQueryable cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

im using Entity Framework designer first and I need to create custom Model Objects starting from the db objects.
I don't want to use IEnumerable cause it will query too many fields.

The goal is to remove the inner select within this function:

```
using (var db = new dbEntities())
{
   var departments= db.departments
                      .Include(p => p.employee)
                      .Where(...)
                      .Select(p => new CustomDepartmentModel()
                      {
                         ID = p.ID,
                         Employees = p.employee
                                .Select(q => new CustomEmployeeModel()
                                {
                                    ID = q.ID,
                                    Name= q.Name
                                }).ToList()
                      });
   return departments.ToList();
}
```

by using this function:

```
public static IQueryable<CustomEmployeeModel> ToModel(this IQueryable<employee> Employee)
    {
        return Employee.Select(u => new CustomEmployeeModel()
        {
            ID = u.ID,
            Name = u.Name
        });
    }
```

But I always get the error: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ToModel".

I did try to use it in these ways without luck:

```
Employees = p.employee.AsQueryable().ToModel().ToList() //1
Employees = db.Entry(p).Collection(f => f.employee).Query().ToModel().ToList() //2
```

I think that I need to use something like this:

```
public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<IQueryable<employee>, IQueryable<CustomEmployeeModel>>> ToModel()
    {
        return p => p.Select(u => new CustomEmployeeModel()
        {
            ID = u.ID,
            Name = u.Name
        });
    }
```

but I really can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that I need to use something like this: [snip] but I really can't figure out how to use it.

That's exactly what you need, but you also need [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to make the query work. With it, your code would look like this:

```
var toModel = ToModel();

var departments2 = db.departments
    .AsExpandable()
    .Include(p => p.employee)
    .Where(p => true)
    .Select(p => new CustomDepartmentModel()
{
    ID = p.ID,
    Employees = toModel.Invoke(p.employee).ToList()
});
```

Comment: Seems great but is it safe to use LINQKit in a serious project? I need to be sure that the code will not broke with entity packages updates. And what about extension methods? do you think that is possible to invoke it in this way: p.employee.ToModel()  ?

Comment: @Simone LINQKit is not EF-specific, it works with any `IQueryable`, so it should work with any version of EF. And I don't see a way how to make this work with an extension method directly; LINQKit looks for invocations of its `Invoke()` and processes that, but it doesn't know that it should process your `ToModel()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that LINQ to Entities is trying to translate your `ToModel()` method into a SQL query (since that's what LINQ to Entities is supposed to do), and it can't find a way to do it, hence the error that you're seeing.

In order for you to call `ToModel()` you'll need to have the information already come in from the database, which will then make any LINQ query a LINQ to Objects query, which will be more than able to do what you are asking for. You can do this by calling `ToList()` before calling `ToModel()`.

Comment: I just want to move the inner select in an external method, I still want to translate the inner select into a sql statement and I don't wanna use ToList() otherwise it will query for other parameters too

Comment: Except that LINQ to Entities is not built that way to allow it. You either need to keep the inner select or call `ToList` first.